# How can I create a custom segue from a custom collection view cell (cell created using xib) to a tabBar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I created a collection view that has custom cells created using a .xib file. I need to create a custom segue that goes to a specific tab of on a tabBar controller depending on the label of the button of the cell. The collection view is basically used as a menu for going to a specific tab of the tabBar controller.

The xib of the custom cell of the collection view has a class of its own. The cell has a button. On clicking the button I need to perform a custom segue (because i need custom animation) from the view controller to the tabBar controller. The collection view is present on the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should explain better the state of the views in order to know if you want to push to another view or simply change the current tab. Anyway, I think you don't need a custom segue, just use the didSelect of the cell, e.g. for obj-c

```
tabBarController.selectedViewController = [tabBar.viewControllers objectAtIndex:SPECIFIC_TAB];
```

Comment: The xib of the custom cell of the collection view has a class of its own. The cell has a button. On clicking the button I need to perform a custom segue (because i need custom animation) from the view controller to the tabBar controller. The collection view is present on the view controller